# ORA-14540: An Online DDL or a DDL with the UPDATE INDEXES clause cannot be used with auto-commit turned off for the DDL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, autocommit

I get this error when 'BEFORE DROP TABLE' trigger is fired.

> ORA-14540: An Online DDL or a DDL with the UPDATE INDEXES clause cannot be used with auto-commit turned off for the DDL

The trigger performs data movement to a different tablespace.

Data movement method used:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MOVE ONLINE ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED NOPARALLEL TABLESPACE new_tbs UPDATE INDEXES (index_name TABLESPACE new_tbs);
```

I am not explicitly setting autocommit off. But it errors out even when autocommit is set to ON and errors out with pragma autonomous_transaction declaration as well.

Comment: what error you get when autocommit is set to ON? Also, does it happen that anytime this table is very large table.